# Save Blob Image with Width & Height VB.Net, MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How can I save image with `Width & Height (360x480)` pixels.

So far this code helps me to convert the image in the `PictureBox` to save it in database.

```
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
        picImage.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png)
        Dim pic_arr As Byte() = New Byte(ms.Length - 1) {}
        ms.Position = 0
        ms.Read(pic_arr, 0, pic_arr.Length)
```

**How can I ADD the feature where I can set the Image Width & Height?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Image` object has `Height` and `Width` properties.  Those are just numbers so you would save them to the database just like you would any other numbers.

Comment: Why would you think I would be waiting here while you checked? Why not just check and then post a comment if appropriate?